# How to Update table data using Column name in where clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-update, multiple-columns

I have following data in a table:

**Table** : `tbl_DevicePrices`

```
id  condition   deviceid    Price
51  Broken       23          50.00
52  New          23          50.00
53  Mint         23          50.00
54  GOOD         23          50.00
55  Fair         23          50.00
56  Poor         23          50.00
81  New          15          350.00
82  Mint         15          350.00
83  GOOD         15          350.00
84  Fair         15          350.00
85  Poor         15          350.00
86  Broken       15          350.00
```

Prices are updated in Excel and which is Uploaded to Update the Values using matching `COLUMN` names and `Device ID` only.

```
DeviceID    Device     Category/Manufacturer    Fair  GOOD  Mint New   Poor Broken
23         Apple 5     iPad/Apple               60    60    60   70    60   60
15         Apple 6     iPad/Apple               400   400   400  450   400  300
```

**Process:**
User will `Edit` the `Prices` in *Excel* sheet and `Upload` this excel sheet to `update prices` of these devices.

**For Example:**
 DeviceID=23 with prices 60,60,60,70,60,60 for their respective `conditions` need to update in `tbl_DevicePrices` by **matching the COLUMN name to the Data in Excel**. i.e **Where** DeviceID=23 and Values of Fair,Good,Mint,New,Poor,Broken to the table `tbl_DevicePrices` for DeviceID=23 and Condition=Broken,New,Mint,Good,Fair,Poor.

**Output Required:**

```
id  condition  deviceid Price
51  Broken      23       60
52  New         23       60
53  Mint        23       70
54  GOOD        23       60
55  Fair        23       60
56  Poor        23       60
81  New         15       450
82  Mint        15       400
83  GOOD        15       400
84  Fair        15       400
85  Poor        15       400
86  Broken      15       300
```

Help Appreciated!

Comment: And your question is? How does the upload process looks now?

Comment: So if a condition doesn't exist it doesn't get updated?  Say in tbl_DevicePrices you didn't have a "fair" condition on device 23.  it doesn't have to create "Fair" does it? and what do you mean uploaded for excel.  Do you mean it's stored in a temporary table? or is it still in the excel document?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question correctly.

Comment: hi all,
All conditions already exists in the table. so their will be no missmatch. Just the thing is i will send the DeviceID, Condition to stored procedure and accordingly need to update the prices.
I am using MSSQlLServer2012

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the excel document (in the below called ExcelUpload) is stored in a temp table and assuming that we don't have to insert new records if a condition is not found...

```
UPDATE tbl_DevicePrices
SET DP.price = case when DP.condition = 'Fair' then xl.fair
                    when DP.condition = 'GOOD' then xl.Good
                    when DP.condition = 'Mint' then xl.Mint
                    when DP.condition = 'new' then xl.new
                    when DP.condition = 'Poor' then xl.Poor
                    when DP.condition = 'Broken' then xl.Broken
                    else dp.Price end
FROM tbl_DevicePrices DP
INNER JOIN ExcelUpload xl
 on xl.deviceID = DP.DeviceID
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume you are loading the Excel table into a database table called, say, `UpdatePrices`.  The following should work in almost any SQL dialect:

```
update tbl_DevicePrices dp
    set price = coalesce((select (case when dp.condition = 'Fair' then up.Fair
                                       when dp.condition = 'Good' then up.Good
                                       . . .
                                  end)
                          from UpdatePrices up
                          where up.deviceid = dp.deviceid
                         ), price);
```